# Cancel call to 'HttpClient.SendAsync()'

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient, cancellation

Is it possible to cancel a call to `HttpClient.SendAsync()`?

I'm sending some data like this:

```
var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "some url");
var multipartFormDataContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
// ... construction of the MultipartFormDataContent. It contains form data + picture file
requestMessage.Content = multipartFormDataContent;
var response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This code works perfectly, but I need to be able to cancel a request on user demand. Is this possible?

I see that there is an [overload of `SendAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh159066%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) that accepts a `CancellationToken` but I don't know how to use it. I also know about a property called `IsCancellationRequested` that indicates if a request has been canceled. But how do I go about actually canceling a request?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `SendAsync` method supports cancellation. You can use the overload which takes a `CancellationToken`, which can be canceled any time you like.

You need to use the `CancellationTokenSource` class for this purpose. The following code shows how to do that.

```
CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
...
var response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage, tokenSource.Token)
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

When you want to cancel the request, call `tokenSource.Cancel();` and you're done.

**Important**: There is no guarantee that cancelling the `CancellationTokenSource` will cancel the underlying operation. It depends upon the implementation of the underlying operation (in this case the `SendAsync` method). The operation could be canceled immediately, after few seconds, or never.

It is worth noting that this is how you'd cancel *any* method which supports `CancellationToken`. It will work with any implementation, not just the `SendAsync` method that is the subject of your question.

For more info, refer to [Cancellation in Managed Threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)